# PHP OOP autoloading class namespaces issue

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, autoload

I am trying to upgrade the code of a new project I am working on to comply with PSR-0.

I am using and SPL loader class, However I may be doing something wrong, I just can't spot what the issue is.

I keep getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'widezike\General' not found in /nfs/c03/h04/mnt/169128/domains/widezike.com/html/beta/lib/functions.php on line 14
```

This is my folder structure:

```
index.php
-lib
config.php
init.php
spl-class-loader.php
functions.php
    -widezike
        -General.php
```

This is my functions file where it begins anything to do with the server side code:

```
<?php

include 'init.php';
include 'config.php';

include 'spl-class-loader.php';

$loader = new SplClassLoader('General', 'lib/widezike');
$loader->register();

use widezike\General;

//Run the output buffer
General::ob();
```

So this is my code for now, but I can't seem to find what's causing the fatal error...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: The error is right at the top, Fatal Error: class 'widezike' etc....

Comment: Can we see autoloader itself?

Comment: I'm using this autoload class unmodified: https://gist.github.com/jwage/221634

Comment: Is spl-class-loader is loaded into the same folder. As you are using the include_once rather require_once() it wont fire any error but there might be a problem.

Comment: i amended my answer to include where spl-loader is however i think it may be a different issue

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a bit of a guess here but I think the issue is in the constructor..

```
$loader = new SplClassLoader('General', 'lib/widezike');
```

In the code you [linked to](https://gist.github.com/jwage/221634) they are the namespace and the include path.

Play around with those until it works is all I can suggest.

You might try:

```
$loader = new SplClassLoader(null, 'lib');
```

Or

```
$load = new SplClassLoad('General', 'lib');
```

On the other hand I personally just use a very simple spl_autoload_register function to do my class loading for me..

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){

    $filename = str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';
    require($filename);

});

$object = new phutureproof\common\whatever();
```

I would then have a file `/phutureproof/common/whatever.php` with the contents:

```
<?php
namespace phutureproof\common;

class whatever
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it might be a different issue, I tried your auto loader and i get the same kind of issue, somehow i think the PHP isn't seperating out the class name and trying to literally load a class called: widezike\General. Using your method i got this: lib/widezike/general.php
Fatal error: Class 'lib\widezike\General' not found in /nfs/c03/h04/mnt/169128/domains/widezike.com/html/beta/lib/functions.php on line 20 I made it print the generated include to make sure that was creating the right thing and it is :S so i'm stumped

Comment: are you putting the right namespace in your classes?
`namespace lib\widezike;

class General {}`

Comment: Well, good luck friend, I can't think of anything else.. hopefully some bright spark will come along and have the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the issue was that my name spaces were wrong, so if you have the same issue just check and make sure that your namespaces are correct!